# python selenium 5xx server error instagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

запускаю через selenium использовал webdriver 0.28.0 и 0.29.0 выводит эту ошибку а в другом браузере все ок как это исправит? Переустанавливал firefox
Такая ошибка у меня со вчерашнего дня

[image: запускаю через selenium использовал webdriver 0.28.0 и 0.29.0 выводит эту ошибку а в другом браузере все ок как это исправит? Переустанавливал firefox]

Answer (score 0):

Версия webdriver и самого браузера должны быть одинаковыми, возможно драйвер устаревший